# Spark submit error - cannot load main class from jar - PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I'm running the below spark submit command, and got an error that says `cannot load main class from jar file:/path/to/dependency.zip` I'm struggling to understand why it looks for main class in the zip file, since I supplied the `application.py`, which has the main class?

What did I miss here? It looks like it's looking for a jar, as if it's considering the application a scala or java app instead of pyspark, in spite of the `--py-files` I specified. Thanks for your help

```
spark-submit \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --pyfiles "/path/to/something.zip","/path/to/dependency.zip" \
  application.py "arg1" "arg2"
```